# Executing script inside python subprocess and getting the output

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to get execute one script with some arguments and getting its out to a buffer for further processing. The original code snippet which works now as below-

```
cmd = "/pathToScript/myscript.sh --endpoint "+ ip_addr + " --register '"+ reg_token + "' --output-file " + pathToOutputFile
os.system(cmd)
```

The above cmd runs and creates the output file where it write the data generated by myhelper script.

Now I want to run the same script, but instead of writing to file, I am expecting the output to a buffer as returned value.

I rewrite the code line as below, but it does not generates the data into buffer.

```
            creds = subprocess.run(
                ["/pathToScript/myscript.sh", "--endpoint {0}".format(endpoint_ipaddr), "--register {0}".format(reg_token)],
                check=True,
                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                universal_newlines=True
            ).stdout
            print("creds")
```

I tried with both subprocess.run() and call() command, but both did not return anything. Is my modified code is correct with respect to executing the script and getting the output collected to returned variable?

Appreciate your help on this.

thank you

Comment: ```print(creds)```?

Comment: intend to capture the output in a buffer variable which was previously being written to output file. forgot to mention the output which is being written to file is first set to one global variable inside script, then written to output file.

Comment: my bad - typos, the value is written to one local variable inside some function and then that value is written to the output file. any way I can fetch that variable value after the script got executed in python  subprocess

Comment: I solved this without using the python's subprocess. Actually I saved the data which was written to file in a buffer and used that inside myscript.sh without returning that value after os.system() is completed.